# node-sass error on any scss file change

Tags: css, node.js, git, bash, sass

I am having a really hard time with node sass (and any other sass software) which is simply giving me errors instead of output. To the point: every time I run --watch on scss file(s) it returns an error which I cannot find the answer to. Frankly, I have no idea what is going on as the scss file is as simple as below 2-liner. css

```
body
    margin: 0
```

Script section in package.json looks like below:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "npm-run-all watch:* ",
    "watch:sass": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true -o css sass --watch",
    "watch:autoprefixer": "onchange -d 100 css/style.css -- autoprefixer-cli -o css/style.prefixed.css css/style.css",
    "watch:browsersync": "browser-sync start --server --files css/*.css *.html",
    "build": "npm run build:clean && npm run build:sass && npm run build:autoprefixer && npm run test",
    "build:clean": "rimraf css/*.css",
    "build:sass": "node-sass --output-style compact -o css sass",
    "build:sass:dev": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true -o css sass",
    "build:autoprefixer": "autoprefixer-cli css/style.css",
    "test": "npm-run-all test:*",
    "test:html": "globstar nu-html-checker *.html",
    "init-project": "npm-run-all init:*",
    "init:dirs": "mkdirp sass css vendor images js",
    "init:files": "touch README.md index.html sass/style.scss js/script.js",
    "init:gitignore": "curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Node.gitignore -o .gitignore",
    "init:npm-install": "npm install"
  },
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.5",
    "autoprefixer-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "glob-run": "^0.1.6",
    "globstar": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "nu-html-checker": "^0.1.0",
    "onchange": "^3.3.0",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "sass-watch": "^0.1.0"
  }
```

Error message from node-sass (shortest possible command I think):

```
$ npm run watch:sass

> 7.7@1.0.0 watch:sass E:\Kodilla\w07\Zadania\7.7
> node-sass -w sass/ -o css/output.css

=> changed: E:\Kodilla\w07\Zadania\7.7\sass\style.scss
=> changed: E:\Kodilla\w07\Zadania\7.7\sass\style.scss
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "E:/Kodilla/w07/Zadania/7.7/sass/style.scss",
  "line": 1,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "Invalid CSS after \"h\": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was \"head\"",
  "formatted": "Error: Invalid CSS after \"h\": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was \"head\"\n        on line 1 of sass/style.scss\n>> head\n   ^\n"
}

$ npm run watch:sass

> 7.7@1.0.0 watch:sass E:\Kodilla\W07\Zadania\7.7
> node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true -o css sass --watch

=> changed: E:\Kodilla\W07\Zadania\7.7\sass\style.scss
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "E:/Kodilla/W07/Zadania/7.7/sass/style.scss",
  "line": 1,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "Invalid CSS after \"h\": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was \"head\"",
  "formatted": "Error: Invalid CSS after \"h\": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was \"head\"\n        on line 1 of sass/style.scss\n>> head\n   ^\n"
}
```

Installed packages (all installed locally):

```
 npm list --depth=0
7.7@1.0.0 E:\Kodilla\W07\Zadania\7.7
+-- autoprefixer@7.2.5
+-- autoprefixer-cli@1.0.0
+-- glob-run@0.1.6
+-- globstar@1.0.0
+-- node-sass@4.7.2
+-- npm-run-all@4.1.2
+-- nu-html-checker@0.1.0
+-- onchange@3.3.0
+-- parallelshell@3.0.2
+-- rimraf@2.6.2
+-- sass@1.0.0-beta.4
`-- sass-watch@0.1.0

$ npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\Radosław Podgórski\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)
```

Cherry on top: when I run npm run watch therer are 3 blocks of errors (from status to formatted) with the same content and after pressing Ctrl+C git bash session freezes - not responsive at all! watch is terminated but the session is killed the very next step.

Maybe the problem is deeper as I tried to use Koala v2.3.0 but it also doesn't work with scss files (?) Error message is (the same 2-liner or any other):

> ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
> Use --trace for backtrace

This problem is related to all scss files (not only 1) I tried also different locations for the whole project and other projects. Koala never worked on my computer. Maybe both problems are totally unrelated. However, maybe there is 1 root cause which affects all possible software on my PC related to scss/css.

> PC configuration:
>
> - OS Name: MS Windows 10 Pro
> - Version: 10.0.16299 Git
> - bash: git version 2.15.1.windows.2
> - node --version: v9.2.0

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Compiling .scss/.sass

The file extension must correspond to the syntax used. The Sass compiler will interpret the contents of the file based on the extension.

You are using the indented Sass syntax with an `.scss` file extension; change the file extension to `.sass` to allow the compiler to correctly interpret your file.

---

#### Use `.sass` file extension with SASS syntax:

```
body
    margin: 0
```

---

#### Use `.scss` file extension with SCSS syntax:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

## Koala and diacritical marks in filepath

Koala cannot deal with diacritical marks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the solution to the problem. Indeed the whole problem was caused by... 1 letter in the extention. Surprisingly, no one (including my mentor didn't catch that). I've been studing web development for 6 weeks and would never catch the problem. Moreover, I also found the problem to KOALA, which shows error (...UTF-8...). My user name default folder contains Polish diacritical marks "Ó" & "Ł" - **KOALA cannot deal with any diacritical marks.**

Comment: Nice find about KOALA and diacrtitcal marks. I added it to the answer. That's a bummer that it doesn't work.

Comment: @RadosławPodgórski If you find this answer is acceptable, would you please kindly accept it? :)

Comment: @ miir Sure, absolutely. Sorry, new to this forum and don't know all the rules as well as fixed behaviours. Anyway, thanks again for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, thank you for accepting my answer! Good luck on your web dev journey and welcome to the stack overflow! I've found stack overflow to be an indispensable resource -- most of the time, people have already asked and answered a lot of the questions we will have. :)